# Caching images with HJCacheClasses error

Tags: iphone, caching, image-caching

I am using `HJCache` lib to cache images in my iPhone app.

I am receiving the following error, but not to all the images, just the first one (not) appearing.

`HJMOFileCache` failed to move loading file to ready file `/Users/joao__garcia/.../Library/Caches/imgcache/ready/http:__uni.....jpg`

The following images it loads with no problem. does anybody know whats going on?

I am getting the directory this way:

```
    objMan = [[HJObjManager alloc] init];
    NSString* cacheDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches/imgcache"] ;
    HJMOFileCache* fileCache = [[HJMOFileCache alloc] initWithRootPath:cacheDirectory];
    objMan.fileCache = fileCache;
```

and then:

```
managedImage = [[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(96, 88, 185, 167)];

managedImage.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:...",video.thumb_video]];
NSLog(@"%@", managedImage.url);

[objMan manage:managedImage];

//    [objMan performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(manage:) withObject:managedImage waitUntilDone:YES];
NSLog(@"image %@", managedImage.image);
[managedImage sizeToFit];
playVideoViewButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:managedImage.image];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for sure what the problem is, but I'd offer some advice on how to pin point where its going wrong.

Have a look at the 'HJCacheClasses/HJMOFileCache.m' file on line 128:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:loadingFilename toPath:readyFilename error:&e];
```

There is nothing there which catches and displays the error, so add a breakpoint at that line and when it fails you should be able to see what the 'e' error is saying. If you can include that in your question, I might be able to tell you what the problem is.